# gb4e: A package specific \ref{}-definition

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, linguistics, gb4e

I use `\usepackage{gb4e}` to reference and to contiuously number my linguistic examples.

It works like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} \label{intro}

\begin{exe}
\ex \label{a} asdf
\end{exe}

In \ref{a} \dots. In \ref{intro} \dots.

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Ideally, the `\ref{a}` output of the `exe` environment would be displayed in brackets while references of other elements like `\section` will still be shown without brackets. So the output would look like this:

[image]

Is anyone there who can solve the problem globally?

Note: I try to avoid to add brackets manually and write *(\ref{})* in the tex file.

Comment: By "brackets" you mean parenthesis, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new command. Below I've called it `\pref` (short for `parenthesis ref`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\newcommand{\pref}[1]{(\ref{#1})}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} \label{intro}
\begin{exe}
    \ex \label{a} asdf
\end{exe}
In \pref{a} \dots. In \ref{intro} \dots.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To be fair, I've stolen this code from somewhere, but I don't remember where. Maybe [here](http://cl.indiana.edu/~md7/13/245/slides/styles/gb4e+.sty).

Comment: Sverre, thank you so much. The attempt is slightly more elegant than the *(\ref{})* but it involves a lot of manual replacing still. I was hoping for a solution that will treat the `ref{}`differently in case it refers to the `exe` environment.

Comment: @Philip How does it involve a lot of manual replacing? You still need to type ``\ref{...}`` when you want a reference, so I don't see how it's any harder to type ``\pref{}``? If necessary, define it as ``\pef``. Then it's exactly the same number of characters.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I would like to use the command for larger documents that are already existing. So in these documents it would be necessary to search for each `\ref{}` manually and replace it if it is a `exe` `\ref{}`. For future documents it doesnt mean manual adjustment.